# Cannot find module 'unsplash-js' or its corresponding type declarations.ts; how to resolve this error; i have installed unsplash-js already

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

I am trying to integrate unsplash api in my ts project and getting error `Cannot find module 'unsplash-js' or its corresponding type declarations.ts` while importing in `.ts` file.

Can someone help?

```
import { createApi } from "unsplash-js"
```

Comment: Seems like you need type definition file. Check if `@types/unsplash-js` exist. I doubt it does.

Comment: You are correct. Its not present; Can you tell me how can I integrate unsplash-js in a ts project;